# Macrium Reflect bootable usb need to be created on the pc inorder for it to see the hdd

Tags: macrium

i realized for some pc brand/model, i need to install the macrium program on the pc itself, then create the usb bootable from it, only then the bootable usb will be able to boot and see the available partition on the pc. If i create it from my laptop and boot at the pc, no hdd will be shown. Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Macrium Reflect creates a bootable media that is based on the environment in
which it was invoked.

From the article
[Macrium Rescue Media Builder](https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW72/Macrium+Rescue+Media+Builder),
I can see at least two variables that might limit the use of the created
bootable media:

> **Architecture**
>
> Choose from 32 or 64 bit.
>   WinRE is only available for the same
>   architecture as the current Windows OS.
>
> **Enable Multi Boot (MBR/UEFI)**
>
> Enables USB media to boot on both MBR and UEFI systems.

Among those two options, only the second one can be set when creating the media.